# Populate a TableView that takes data from two different classes

Tags: java, javafx

I currently have two classes one is AddressDetails and the other is Results. 
What I would like to happen is that the table fills with the values from both however currently it only fills from AddressDetails.

My TableView code is:

```
table = new TableView<AddressDetails>(); 

    TableColumn<AddressDetails, String> address = new TableColumn<>("Full Address");
    TableColumn<AddressDetails, String> buildingName = new TableColumn<>("Building Name");
    TableColumn<AddressDetails, Double> buildingNum = new TableColumn<>("Building Number");
    TableColumn<AddressDetails, String> streetNam = new TableColumn<>("Street Name");
    TableColumn<AddressDetails, String> cityName = new TableColumn<>("City");
    TableColumn<AddressDetails, String> postcode = new TableColumn<>("Postcode");
    TableColumn<AddressDetails, String> countryName = new TableColumn<>("Country");
    TableColumn<Results, String> connect = new TableColumn<>("Connectivity Result");

    buildingName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("buildName"));
    buildingNum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("buildNum"));
    streetNam.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("streetName"));
    cityName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("city"));
    postcode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("postCode"));
    countryName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("country"));
    connect.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("connect"));

    // Add columns of the address details to full address column 
    address.getColumns().addAll(buildingName, buildingNum, streetNam, cityName, postcode, countryName);
    table.getColumns().addAll(address, connect);
```

Results Class:

```
public class Results {

private String connect;

public Results() {

}
*Constructor, getters and setters
```

AddressDetails class:

```
public class AddressDetails {

private String buildName;
private double buildNum;
private String streetName;
private String city;
private String postCode;
private String country;
//private Results result;

public AddressDetails() {

}
*Constructor, getters and setters
```

I would have created a class that contains all object but currently AddressDetails gets its values from reading and excel file and Results gets its values from an API call and so I'm guessing that I need to put AddressDetails and Results into another class so that I can call my TableView this something like TableView. However I am not sure how to go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm new to JavaFX and Java so don't have a great understanding especially with TableViews.

Comment: The easiest route would be to create a new class that represents both of the old classes and dump the old classes.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a way to re-use the same data class to get data from SQL. Unfortunately, I couldn't get reflection working for ApacheDBUtils to use SimpleStringProperty or SimpleIntegerProperty (as required for `TableView`). However, using a `MapListHandler`, you can populate the fields manually. Basically, make the model class for `TableView` be your data class as well.

Address.java

```
package fx;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Address
{

    private final StringProperty city;
    private final StringProperty country;

    public Address()
    {
        this.city = new SimpleStringProperty();
        this.country = new SimpleStringProperty();
    }

    public static List<Address> getAddressesFromMap(List<Map<String, Object>> addressResults)
    {
        List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map<String, Object> addressResult : addressResults)
        {
            Address address = new Address();
            address.setCity((String) addressResult.get("city"));
            address.setCountry((String) addressResult.get("country"));
            addresses.add(address);

        }
        return addresses;
    }

    /**
     * @return the city
     */
    public StringProperty getCity()
    {
        return city;
    }

    /**
     * @return the country
     */
    public StringProperty getCountry()
    {
        return country;
    }

    /**
     * @param city the city to set
     */
    public void setCity(String city)
    {
        this.city.set(city);
    }

    /**
     * @param country the country to set
     */
    public void setCountry(String country)
    {
        this.country.set(country);
    }

}
```

SQLManager.java

```
package fx;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.DbUtils;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.handlers.MapListHandler;

public class SQLManager
{

    public List<Address> getAddresses()
    {

        Connection connection = createConnection();
        List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Map<String, Object>> addressResults = new ArrayList<>();

        if (connection == null)
        {
            return addresses;
        }

        try
        {
            addressResults = new QueryRunner().query(connection, "SELECT * From address;", new MapListHandler());

        } catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(SQLManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } finally
        {

            try
            {
                DbUtils.close(connection);

            } catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(SQLManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
        addresses.addAll(Address.getAddressesFromMap(addressResults));

        return addresses;
    }


    private Connection createConnection()
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        try
        {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("db.connection", "db.user", "db.pass");

        } catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(SQLManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
package fx;

import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");

        TableView table = new TableView<Address>();
        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new SQLManager().getAddresses()));

        TableColumn<Address, String> cityCol = new TableColumn<>("City");
        cityCol.setCellValueFactory(features -> features.getValue().getCity());

        TableColumn<Address, String> countryCol = new TableColumn<>("Country");
        countryCol.setCellValueFactory(features -> features.getValue().getCountry());

        table.getColumns().addAll(cityCol, countryCol);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(table);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```