# How can I update a database using all the data of a tableView without selecting its items?

Tags: javafx

I need to update a whole information of one of the columns of my database from the changes the user makes in the tableView just with the act of a button, but I have no idea how to use it. I thought about using the `listview.forEach()` to it goes through each of the items. How can I get the information from the table using `forEach` to update the database?

Here's my TableController:

```
package sempre.alerta.financeiro;

import connection.ConnectionClasse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author Mayumi Liz
 */
public class TabelaVisaoGeralController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane AnchorPaneTabelaVisaoGeral;
    @FXML
    private MenuBar mnbMenuVisaoGeral;
    @FXML
    private Menu mnuOpcoes;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem mnuiNovo;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem mnuiEditar;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem mnuiApagar;
    @FXML
    private Menu mnuAtualizar;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem mnuiAtualizarDados;
    @FXML
    private Menu mnuAjuda;
    @FXML
    private MenuItem mnuiSobre;
    @FXML
    private TableView<TabelaGeral> tableTabelaVisaoGeral;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TabelaGeral, String> tbcUEB;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TabelaGeral, String> tbcNome;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TabelaGeral, String> tbcData;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TabelaGeral, String> tbcRamo;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TabelaGeral, Boolean> tbcCondicao;

    public String sql;

    ObservableList<TabelaGeral> listview = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    int x = 0;
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */

    @FXML
    private void mnuNovo(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("menu Novo");
       AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("TelaCadastro.fxml"));
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { //esse método permite controlar objetos graficos a partir de outras classes
  @Override
  public void run() {
   TelaMenuController.controleMenu.AnchorPaneTelas.getChildren().setAll(pane);
  }
}); 
    }    

    @FXML
    private void mnuApagar(ActionEvent event) {
    TabelaGeral tabela = tableTabelaVisaoGeral.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(); //vetor que tem valor do objeto selecionado na tabela
    String ueb = tabela.getCodigoueb();

    try {
    ConnectionClasse cn = new ConnectionClasse();
          Connection cn1 = cn.fileconnection();

          PreparedStatement stmt = cn1.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM cadastro WHERE codigoueb = '"+ ueb + "'");
           stmt.execute();
    }
     catch(Exception e){

     }
        tableTabelaVisaoGeral.getItems().removeAll(tabela); //remove da TABELA
        System.out.println(ueb + " deletado.");
    }

     @FXML
    private void mnuiAtualizarDados(ActionEvent event) {
    listview.forEach(item -> { //I thought about introducing the code to update the database right here.     
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        RamosController tabela = new RamosController();
        tbcUEB.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("codigoueb"));
        tbcNome.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nome"));
        tbcData.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("datadenasc"));
        tbcRamo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ramo"));
         tbcCondicao.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("selected"));

        try{
          ConnectionClasse cn = new ConnectionClasse();
          Connection cn1 = cn.fileconnection();

          if (tabela.tipo == "lobinhos"){
          sql = "SELECT * FROM CADASTRO WHERE ramo = 'Lobinhos'";
          }
          if (tabela.tipo == "escoteiros"){
          sql = "SELECT * FROM CADASTRO WHERE ramo = 'Escoteiros'";
          }
          if (tabela.tipo == "senior"){
          sql = "SELECT * FROM CADASTRO WHERE ramo = 'Sênior'";
          }
          if (tabela.tipo == "pioneiros"){
          sql = "SELECT * FROM CADASTRO WHERE ramo = 'Pioneiros'";
          }
          if (tabela.tipo == "geral") {
          sql = "SELECT * FROM CADASTRO";
          }
          Statement s = cn1.createStatement();
          ResultSet r = s.executeQuery(sql); //ResultSet é uma tabela de dados que representa um conjunto de dados do BD.

           while(r.next())
           {
               listview.add(new TabelaGeral(
                       r.getString("DATADENASC"),
                       r.getString("NOME"),
                       r.getString("RAMO"),
                       r.getString("CODIGOUEB"),
                       r.getBoolean("PAGO")
               ));
           }
            tbcCondicao.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(tbcCondicao)); //renderiza o campo Condição
           //como uma checkBox.

           tableTabelaVisaoGeral.setItems(listview);

           //con.close();
       } catch(Exception e) {

       }
    }    

}
```

And here's my fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="AnchorPaneTabelaVisaoGeral" prefHeight="416.0" prefWidth="517.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sempre.alerta.financeiro.TabelaVisaoGeralController">
   <children>
      <MenuBar fx:id="mnbMenuVisaoGeral" layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="517.0">
        <menus>
          <Menu fx:id="mnuOpcoes" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Opções">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="mnuiNovo" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#mnuNovo" text="Novo" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="mnuiEditar" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Editar" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="mnuiApagar" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#mnuApagar" text="Apagar" />
               </items></Menu>
            <Menu fx:id="mnuAtualizar" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Atualizar">
              <items>
                <MenuItem fx:id="mnuiAtualizarDados" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#mnuiAtualizarDados" text="Atualizar dados" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu fx:id="mnuAjuda" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Ajuda">
              <items>
                <MenuItem fx:id="mnuiSobre" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Sobre" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <TableView fx:id="tableTabelaVisaoGeral" editable="true" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="390.0" prefWidth="517.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="tbcUEB" prefWidth="69.0" text="UEB" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="tbcNome" prefWidth="226.0" text="Nome" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="tbcData" prefWidth="86.0" text="Data de nasc." />
            <TableColumn fx:id="tbcRamo" prefWidth="83.0" text="Ramo" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="tbcCondicao" prefWidth="52.0" text="Pago" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Hi, can you add the code snippet from where you are trying to do this? I think that will help clear up the question for someone to be able to assist!

Here's a link to how to format your post as well via StackOverflow's markdown support: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Done! Sorry, btw, I'm new here haha

Comment: You should use something like Apache DBUtils to get your Select statements automatically mapped to a model class. Then your `TableView` will contain a list of these items. I made an example from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54581653/9278333 , then it's quite simply creating a batch statement that updates all of the items from the table.